# Take out string parts and number parts of string

Tags: regex

I may have strings that will look something like this:

```
ABC
DEF-123
456
789GH-IJK-0
```

And Im trying to figure out a Regex that will group it on strings and numbers, like this:

```
(ABC)
(DEF-)(123)
(456)
(789)(GH-IJK-)(0)
```

My first thought was to use (\D*|\d*) as pattern, but the numbers isnt returned

Comment: if you change the `*` to `+` it should work

Comment: @mhyfritz: no, then it would become exactly the same as .+

Comment: @Andrew White: both `+` and `|` are greedy, so it will work. In python `re.findall(r'(\D+|\d+)', "789GH-IJK-0")` gives `['789', 'GH-IJK-', '0']`, just as asked for...

Comment: Both ((?:\D+)|(?:\d+)) and (\D+|\d+) gave the result I were looking for. I went for ((?:\D+)|(?:\d+)) since it gave the cleanest code.

Comment: @mhyfritz, @Inmx:  I stand corrected. I didn't realize | was greedy as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using inner non-capturing sub groups...

```
((?:\D+)|(?:\d+))
```

Example output from perl...

```
cat input | perl -ane 'chomp; print "looking at $_\n"; while(/((?:\D+)|(?:\d+))/g) {print "Found $1\n";}'
looking at BC
Found BC
looking at DEF-123
Found DEF-
Found 123
looking at 456
Found 456
looking at 789GH-IJK-0
Found 789
Found GH-IJK-
Found 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use + instead of * on the alternatives:

```
(\D+|\d+)
```

Comment: No, that will match anything, you are saying match any digit or non digit more than one. That's like saying .+

Comment: I tested the pattern in regulator (.NET) and it produced the correct results.

Comment: @Inmx: I edited your answer so that I could remove my eronous down vote. My apologies and a +1.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working, but quite ugly (backslash-plague). Instead of doing one regexp, separate it into two, one to handle digits and one for characters.

```
$ sed 's/\([a-zA-Z-]\+\)/(\1)/g ; s/\([0-9]\+\)/(\1)/g' input
(BC)
(DEF-)(123)
(456)
(789)(GH-IJK-)(0)
```